# Find Duplicates, if beside cells is this and this value do this

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates

ColumnA-------------ColumnB

Duplicate Number----M-946

Duplicate Number----M-954

or vise versa

Duplicate Number----M-954

Duplicate Number----M-946

If in each Group of 2 duplicates as Value in ColumnB is as described in the above example, is true. Then color Both Column A and B a different color.

Code that colors rows that are only 2times duplicate. 
See this:

```
Sub find2duplicatesonly()
      Dim cel As Variant
      Dim myrng As Range

      Set myrng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
      myrng.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone

      For Each cel In myrng
      clr = 10
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(myrng, cel) = 2 Then
          cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 26
      clr = clr + 10

      End If
      Next

      MsgBox ("All duplicates found and coloured")

End Sub
```

this is me trying:

Where am i going wrong?

```
Public Sub testcode1()
    Dim rngFound As Range
    Dim strFirst As String
    Dim varFind As Variant

    For Each varFind In Array("M-954", "M-946")

        Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(varFind, Cells(Rows.Count, "B"), xlValues, xlPart)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then

            strFirst = rngFound.Address

            Do
                Set rngFound = Columns("B").Find(varFind, rngFound, xlValues, xlPart)

            Loop While rngFound.Address <> strFirst
            Select Case varFind

                Case "M-954" & "M-946": Call find2duplicatesonly

            End Select

        End If
    Next varFind

End Sub
```

Comment: Add more details of what you have and explanation of what you want - re-edit your post to state all of your objectives together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [Conditional Formatting](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/find-duplicates.html).  That page mentions how to do specifically duplicates, but if your "duplicates search" is a little more complex, you can look into making your own formula for the conditional formatting [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/10/excel-conditional-formatting-formulas/)

Edit: After discussion (see below comments), Conditional Formatting might work but I couldn't get it to highlight BOTH cells, only one at a time.  I have therefore written this VB Code:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim lastRow As Double, matchString1 As String, matchString2 As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, cel As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet

matchString1 = "Superman"
matchString2 = "Batman"

With ws
    lastRow = .Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lastRow, 1))

    For Each cel In rng
        If (cel.Value = matchString1 And cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = matchString2) Or _
            (cel.Value = matchString2 And cel.Offset(1, 0).Value = matchString1) Then
            With .Range(.Cells(cel.Row, cel.Column), .Cells(cel.Row + 1, cel.Column)).Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 65535
            End With
        End If
    Next cel
End With
End Sub
```

Note, you can change "Superman" and "Batman"  to whatever you need.  Also, if this changes each time, you can set this to refer to a cell's value (i.e. `matchString1 = Cells(1,2).Value`). This resulted with this coloring: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vGbNs.jpg)

Also, do you need anything done with those first three "Batman"?

Comment: I just realized that it can only work if there is only a total of 2 duplicates in column A as sometimes i have more but i dont want to change those. Could it be still be done with Conditional Formatting?

Comment: So, you only want to highlight 2 duplicates, even if there are 1000?  How do you determine which two you want highlighted?

Comment: see my added code in edit... just figured out how to do that. But i still want to go through those that were highlighted and only color those with the values as mentioned in OP

Comment: Can someone please help me figure out how to define code to only look at the 2 values being together top and bottom of each other?

Comment: Thank you for letting me know about conditonal formatting. I just realized how powerful that tool is. Thanks!

Comment: @MaximTeleguz - did you figure it out? I was away from computer for a few days but can help if you didn't get it working.

Comment: no i never got the chance to do that. mngmt said that was one small step to not waste time on and swamped me with other work. I would love to figure it out though...

Comment: Sorry, I confused myself.  So, you have a list of Duplicates, and running your `find2duplicatesonly()` will highlight all duplicates, except 1. (So if you have "batman" three times, it'll highlight 2 of them).  What do you want to do from here again?

Comment: sorry, those numbers arent duplicates. But that was the only way i could phrase it. Basically it will do a loop of all the numbers and if those 2 specifically are arranged like that lets say batman and superman are sideby side highlight both of them if its batman and batman and superman only batman and supeman will be highlighted the first batman will stay behind.

Comment: Can you post some sample (can be fake) data? First without the "result", then with what you expect.  Is it like this? "If batman and superman are side by side...", so I have A1:B1 highlighted.  "...if it's batman and batman and superman only...", so I have highlighted the *second* and *third* (and would do fourth, fifth, etc. as applicable) repetitions of "Batman" and "Superman"...is this the highlighting you're looking for?  [Here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/BXQGoiH.jpg)

Comment: basically for each batman it finds, it will look to see if next cell is superman, same with for each superman it finds it will check to see if next cell is batman.

Comment: Aha! So basically the *only* cells to be highlighted are if the cell is `Batman` and the cell either above or below is `Superman`, highlight both.  Same for the opposite (if a cell is `Superman`, if above or below is `Batman`, highlight both.  I'll update my OP in a minute.

Comment: BruceWayne I want to be like you someday... how you solved it i have no idea. IT works! thanks!

Comment: @MaximTeleguz haha, well thanks - just keep at it!  I use the Macro Recorder, which helps show you generally how to do things, learning how to not use `.Select` is a big step, and finally of course, just Google!  If you have any questions about the code, don't hesitate to let me know!